# How to set value of variable in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, procedure

How can I use custom function in sql query to set value of some variable.

My function is:

```
function myFunc(par){return par;}
```

My SQL query is:

```
 const string query =
            @"
            DECLARE @result varchar(100)
            SET @result= myFunc(N'test')

            INSERT[dbo].[TempTable] ([Name]) 
            VALUES (@result)
            ";
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: 2014 and btw this code is written in Migration, not in Configuration.cs class

Comment: In SQL Server, you need to specify the schema name when calling the function . . . `dbo.myfunc(N'test')`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the schema that this function belongs to.  Assuming it is in schema `dbo`, just change this line:

```
SET @result= myFunc(N'test')
```

to

```
SET @result= dbo.myFunc(N'test')
```

If you like, you can half the size of the overall query by inserting directly from the function output - no @variable required:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TempTable (Name) 
SELECT dbo.myFunc(N'test')
```

Comment: I do that and get the following error: **Cannot find either column "myFunc" or the user-defined function or aggregate "myFunc", or the name is ambiguous.**

Comment: I have updated my answer; I'd answered on-the-fly and misunderstood what the problem was.  @GordonLinoff was correct in his comment.